# Autodesk Eagle check via layers

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, via

is there a way with Eagle to check all the via ?

I want to be sure that they are all vias from 1-16 layers.

I found manually a via 1-15 ( my mistake during placing it )

Is there a way with the error/rule checking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with Eagle 9.6.2. Eagle has changed quite a lot in the last 5 years so there may be some differences.

1. Disable the option to place the vias that are not 1-16 in the first place. In *DRC-> Layers* remove the via options that you don't want. After that it should not be possible to use it.
   [image: DRC->Layers]
2. Check the *Manufacturing->Drills* tab. All holes are displayed there and you may spot the intrudes here.
   [image: Manufacturing->Drills]
3. After generating you gerber data, check the drilling files. There only should be drill file named something like this `drill_1_16.xln`. Any other files indicating that you may have buried vias.

[image]